# Smartphone on usb rings on computer

Tags: usb, ringtone

I got a smartphone on android, and when it is attached trough USB to my computer (windows or linux), I'd like to have it ring or do notifications in the headphones of the computer.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Bluetooth you can very well get it. After the bluetooth connection is established, you can use the bluetooth menu to activate

1. playback of music from Phone on Computer,
2. Receive call on Computer which you have a option to take it on the hand phone if you want ( this is available on the android phone screen page when the call is in activation)
3. To exchange the files between the computer and phone
4. SMS the message from computer that goes via phone.

Comment: That sounds good, so what do you have to do to make this work?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this happen on my laptop with an Atheros BT chip. After pairing the phone with the PC, the phone will show options for streaming audio to the PC in the Bluetooth menu. When connected, the PC will show a Windows Media Player-like interface for controlling playback.

Answer (score 0):

No. As far as I know, this is not possible.

May be this can be done through custom application. But I think there is no app that does this, at least, for now.